# Escape sequence in path

Tags: python

```
source = "C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\yyy\Agent\node.default\blr-w2k8-252\data\somefile.iso"
print source
```

output:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\yyy\Agent
 ode.defaulblr-w2k8-252\data\somefile.iso"
```

Notice that for `\n`ode  I got a new line and deaful`t\`blr is gone

I did `source=source.replace('\\', '/')`  but got same output even `/n` is also causing new line.

I did `source=source.encode('string-escape')` now the output is something else

output:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\xxx\\yyy\\Agent\node.default\x08lr-w2k8-252\\data\\somefile.iso"
```

Only a raw string is working i.e

```
source=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\yyy\Agent\node.default\blr-w2k8-252\data\somefile.iso"
```

But in my program I only have the string variable. How to make it work or how to make the string variable as raw ?

Comment: What do you mean by the string variable? How is the value of that variable set?

Comment: Here I have hard coded, but in the program some method is passing the path as string in to the variable.

Comment: Use forward slashes even on windows.

Comment: The `\n` in non-raw string literals is interpreted *immediately* - before your code gets a chance to do the `replace` or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying "r" before a string literal doesn't change the data type of the string; it just affects how the string literal is interpreted. So your problem is likely the way that the information is collected into the string, not how the string is stored once it has been collected. Note as well that when you print a string in Python, the output automatically includes escape characters (such as the double-slashes in your "output:" example). The string only includes one slash even though both are shown.

Comment: But when using that source variable I am doing shutil.copy(source, target)

I am getting error that :

Error in copying : [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or
 filename: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\xxx\\yyy\\Agent\node.default\x08lr-w2k8-
252\\data\\somefile.iso'

Comment: @Reuben - That error could only have happened if you specified the string as non-raw - the reason being it has `\n` rather than `\\n` at the `Agent\node.default` bit - that's `\n` as in line-feed. The error is adding escaping to the error to mimic the normal string literal notation (and so non-printing characters are readable). Try using raw string literals with your actual code (calling `shutil.copy`) and see what happens. I've tried it with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [escape sequences](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex10.html). Using 'r' before a string tells Python to ignore escape sequences and take the string literally. When you hard code source to a value it is different than when source's value is assigned from calling a function. If it is not working, check how the function you are calling creates that path.